# Converting Single Array into variable

Tags: php, wordpress

from the below Code 2 references Code 2 via $sendData. I would like to completely remove Code 1, and only using Code 2. Can I please get help writing code 1 into code 2, perhaps in form of array

**CODE 1**

```
$sendData = '{ "messages" : [ { "content" :  "Hello", "destination" : "0718860000" } ] }';
```

**CODE 2**

```
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => array("Content-Type: application/json", $authHeader),
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => $sendData,
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
$options = [
    'http' => [
        'header'  => [ "Content-Type: application/json", $authHeader ],
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => json_encode([
            "messages" => [
                [ 
                    "content" => "Hello",
                    "destination" => "0718860000",
                ],
            ],
        ]),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow @BrightMtabela! Please mark the answer as "accepted" left to the answer if you are satisfied, this helps other users to quickly find the best answer to your question in the future.